# Show and hide UIPickerView in a TableView without moving the rows

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to show a UIPickerView on top of a table of rows I've created. However, when I place the UIPickerView on my Storyboard and show/hide it, it leaves a blank space where the Picker was. How can I remove the picker completely and make the rest of the rows fill the space?

[image: Storyboard UI]

EDIT: I finally fixed the issue. It was extremely difficult to find the correct info. A lot of the answers are saying to set a height constraint outlet, which I tried to do but there was no way to get the height outlet from IB into my code. I even tried putting it into a stack view and couldn't get the outlet to work either. However I was able to get the frame size and set the frame size like so:

```
// hide
StoryTypePickerView.isHidden = true
let size = StoryTypePickerView.frame.size
StoryTypePickerView.frame.size = CGSize(width: size.width, height: 0)

// show
StoryTypePickerView.isHidden = false
let size = StoryTypePickerView.frame.size
StoryTypePickerView.frame.size = CGSize(width: size.width, height: 100)
```

If there's a better way, I would be happy to hear it. This works for me for the time being.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: set picker view height constrain programatically.

Comment: You can take Height Constraint for your pickerView and change according to your need.

Comment: you can add pickerView in tableViewHeader. just set header height and reload data.

Comment: There's no constraint for setting the PickerView height so I can't add it as an IBOutlet. How can I change the height programmatically?

Comment: @SagarChauhan I didn't have the code yet, everything was in IB. I couldn't figure out where to set the height in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Take height outlet of Picker view .when you want to show the Pickerview that time set height of pickerview(Ex. self.height.constant = 160) and when you want to hide picker that time set height of pickerview as 0.

Comment: I'm still stumped here, I don't see how to get the height outlet of the picker view.

Comment: First of all set pickerView height .After that select height constraint and drag to your controller . This process is same as you outlet UILabel ,UITextField etc. Link : https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-PS--FNZHZ-o/XC7gY4q2t_I/AAAAAAAABWU/nt6LjlPEf0As-3dlU_29jx1emr6BLQWuQCL0BGAYYCw/h311/2019-01-03.png

Comment: It wouldn't let me set a height constraint in the picker view. The option was completely blocked out.

Answer (score 1):

Create view includes date picker above the tableview and give height constraint to container view. When your hiding the view make the hight contrints value to 0 and vice versa... Hope it will work!.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the issue. It was extremely difficult to find the correct info. A lot of the answers are saying to set a height constraint outlet, which I tried to do but there was no way to get the height outlet from IB into my code. I even tried putting it into a stack view and couldn't get the outlet to work either. However I was able to get the frame size and set the frame size like so:

```
// hide
StoryTypePickerView.isHidden = true
let size = StoryTypePickerView.frame.size
StoryTypePickerView.frame.size = CGSize(width: size.width, height: 0)

// show
StoryTypePickerView.isHidden = false
let size = StoryTypePickerView.frame.size
StoryTypePickerView.frame.size = CGSize(width: size.width, height: 100)
```

If there's a better way, I would be happy to hear it. This works for me for the time being.